# is echo the only way to send data from php to jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if there can be other ways to send something from PHP to jquery instead

```
echo $data_to_jquery;
```

Comment: You need a way to generate output by PHP. One of them is `echo`, and for simple strings and json data, is the best. Some another functions: [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php), [`printf`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) and ... .

Comment: write code out side <?PHP tag. :)

Answer (score 2):

These are several ways to generate output from a php script

For Textual data:

[echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) or the alternate `<?= ... ?>` syntax

[print](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) and [printf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

Anything outside of `<?php ... ?>` is output

[fpassthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) on an open file handle

[fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php), [fputs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php), [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), [fprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fprintf.php) to an open handle on php://stdout or php://output

For Images

[imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)
[imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)
[imagegif](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php)
[imagewbmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewbmp.php)

I'm probably missing several.

Comment: "I'm probably missing several." - There are *dozens* of other ways to generate output, though I'd rather not get into the details.